# how to access private github repos using yaml

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to find a way to access my private github repo via my YAML pipeline which runs in azure devops. I can create PAT access tokens, but do i need to copy this token and paste it as a secret value within github -> repo -> settings -> secret? and how would i access this token to get access to my github private repo? i have the following steps though not sure if this works:

```
steps:
  - shell: pwsh
    env:
      SUPER_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    run: |
      example-command "$env:SUPER_SECRET"
```

what are the yaml tasks i need to access my gihuh repo? i know using below i can access public repos but not private ones:

```
  repositories:
    - repository: myrepo
      endpoint: svc-github
      name: projecta/privaterepo
      type: github
```

Any ideas on this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use a private github repository from your YAML pipeline, you have to grant authorization for it :

- Go to the settings of your Azure devOps project on Azure DevOps
- Select "Service connections"
- You have to create a new GitHub service connection and give access to your private repository
- After that, specify the service connection created inside "endoint:"

So, you will obtain something like that :

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: common
    type: github
    name: Contoso/CommonTools
    endpoint: [your service connection name]
```

Azure DevOps documentation section about it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#resources-repositories

I hope this will help you.